# How can I instantiate a variable in a try block?

Tags: c++

What's the best way to achieve:

```cpp
for (const auto &arg : args) {
    try {
        auto var = create(arg);
    } catch (const std::invalid_argument &e) {
        continue;
    }
    // ...
    // use(var)
    // ...
}
```

One way is to move

```cpp
    // ...
    // use(var)
    // ...
```

into the try block, but this introduces a whole load of nesting. Also, I don't want to catch errors from `use`

`typeof(var)` is a class with no default constructor.

Comment: You will need to use an explicit type for `var` (instead of `auto`) and move the declaration (but not the assignment) above the `try` statement.

Comment: @Dai `typeof(var)` has no default constructor

Comment: Use `std::optional`.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi If the type-of `var` doesn't have a default-constructor then use a placement-new.

Comment: @Dai I knew I could resort to HEAP allocating the object and using a pointer; I didn't want to because it overcomplicates (and slows down) the scenario.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi Why would it "slow down" your program - or overcomplicate things?

Answer (score 1):

> *One way is to move `use(var)` into the try block, but this introduces a whole load of nesting*

You could move `use(var)` out to a separate function and call that in your `try` block:

```
void use(var_type var) {
    //...
}
```

```
for(const auto& arg : args) {
    try {            
        use(create(arg));
    } catch(const std::invalid_argument& e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Since you have no control over `create` or the `use` block and want to make sure that you don't catch anything thrown in the `use` block, you can catch and rethrow the `create` exception as a different type to be able to catch that only. Since exceptions should only happen in exceptional cases, this overhead should not be any problem.

Example:

```
struct create_error : std::invalid_argument {
    using std::invalid_argument::invalid_argument;
    explicit create_error(const std::invalid_argument& e) : std::invalid_argument(e) {}
};

auto create_wrapper(const arg_type& arg) {
    try {
        return create(arg);
    }
    catch(const std::invalid_argument& ex) {
        throw create_error(ex);
    }
}

void use(var_type var) {
    // may throw std::invalid_argument, but it won't be caught below
}
```

```
for(const auto& arg : args) {        
    try {
        use(create_wrapper(arg));
    }
    catch(const create_error& e) {
        continue;
    }        
}
```

Comment: If an `invalid_argument` is thrown from `use(var)` then it would be caught - that may not be the intention of the programmer who may only want to catch `invalid_argument` only for `create` but not `use`.

Comment: This was another idea I had, but this is not really useful - as it introduces indirection

Comment: Also @Dai is correct. That's another reason (i forgot) that I wanted the code outside the try block

Comment: Ok, both `create` and `use` may throw `invalid_argument`? Perhaps there's some underlaying design issue to take care of in that case. Create separate exceptions for the two functions. Indirection: I wouldn't worry about the reference being passed to `use` I doubt you'll be able to measure the effect.

Comment: @TedLyngmo there's no issue. I didn't claim that `use` throws an `invalid_argument` exception, but I'm only interested in catching the error thrown from `create` - thus, It's all that needs to be in the try block.

Comment: Ok, but if it's only `create` that may throw `invalid_argument` then calling `use` as suggested should do exactly what you need.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Okay, lets say `use` does throw an invalid argument exception; that's not a problem. So, this isn't a valid solution. Above you assume there's some fundamental problem with the code base - which is confusing, it's a valid scenario

Comment: throws a `std::invalid_argument` exception*

Comment: Then, define different exceptions for the two functions as I suggested?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not in control of the errors thrown; that's why I make no claims on what's thrown by `use`. Also, defining other errors is not a solution, it's a hack

Comment: That's a pretty odd situation then, but you are in control of the `use` block so you can make that throw something else than `invalid_argument`? "_defining other errors is not a solution, it's a hack_" - What on earth gave you that idea?! If you look at many of the best libraries around, you'll find a lot of added exceptions. The standard exceptions provide a base but can't possibly fit every case.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I'm not in control of `use` - even if I were, there are other calls internally I wouldn't be in control of.

Comment: Can you make a [mcve] and put that in your question? It's starting to feel like you're trapped in a bad situation. I added an alternative.

Comment: The code is moved into the try block, I explicit said this was something I didn't want - so that is the part of the answer that doesn't fulfill my needs.

Comment: @TobyAkinyemi The reason you gave doesn't really apply when moving it to a separate function though - and it'll be hard to make a more effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe `std::optional` is what you need. you can use it with Class with no default constructor, as follows

If you are not interested to know for what values the exceptions have been thrown, you can use something like the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

struct A{
    int var;
    explicit A(int arg):var{arg}{}
    A() = delete ;
};
A create( int arg){
    if (arg == 5 || arg == 8)
        throw std::invalid_argument{""};
    return A{arg};
}

void use(const A & a)
{
    std::cout << "\n" << a.var;
}
int main()
{
    std::optional<A> a;
    for (size_t i{}; i < 10; ++i) {
        try {
            a = create(i);
        } catch (const std::invalid_argument &e) {
                continue;
        }
        if(a) use(a.value());

    }

}
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/W15hYj)

Comment: If you're (ab)using a `vector<T>` to represent "zero-or-one-of-`T`" then why use `optional`<T> at all (or rather: why use `vector` when you have `optional` already)? With `vector` the space for `T` may be allocated on the heap, with `optional` it's guaranteed that the space will be allocated locally).

Comment: Could you strip out the vector usage and the second loop - that's outside the scope of this question - I understand you may have used it for prototyping your answer

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi since you have a range of vars you need a container. right

Comment: I store the object in a local variable, not an array. I'm not interested in old values - this is overcomplicating the scenario

Comment: @asmmo The local variable is inside the loop; you also don't have a `use`; this isn't the same scenario.

Comment: @asmmo Why not have it as your answer? Neither of the snippets in this post are solutions to the scenario.

Comment: Also, `use` doesn't take an `optional` as parameter, but a `typeof(var)`

Comment: @asmmo It's what you assume to be more general purpose. It also means you've consciously posted something that's not an answer. You've also overcomplicated the scenario

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work:

```
template<typename T>
struct initializing {
    T self;
    template<typename F>
    initializing(F &&f) : self(std::forward<F>(f)()) { }
};

for(auto const &arg : args) {
    std::optional<initializing<std::decay_t<decltype(create(arg))>>> var_opt;
    try { var_opt.emplace([&]() -> decltype(auto) { return create(arg); }); }
    catch(std::invalid_argument const &e) { continue; }
    auto &var = var_opt->self;
}
```

[Complete example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tEAFZSW9ABk8tTADljAI0zFzAZlIAHVAsLqtHqGJuY%2BfgF0tvZORq7uZl5KKmp0DATMxATBxqYWyZiqgemZBNGOLm6eihlZOaH5tWV2FXFViQCUiqgGxMgcAORSHnbIhlgA1OIeOnYBbHgAXm4A%2Bqx4CgTT2OIADACCw6PjmFMz6pvEmMxG23uHkiO0YwaT03reqbRsdwdHzyczjoFJdrrcPDs/o9jq9Tu8CABPbyYFYEYjMQgKX4PJ4vN4zAxqdaI7H3AiYIzeYTk%2BFIrQ3U4AFWxlwMqgmczUC0WdmAUwA7LIDhMRRNGRNklRpkL9qKJuTKdTMLTkd8jKcAGLYuWcvDc3kQDVTSQANikJqoHQmIAlyioEE26BAIBoxAA7pl0O8tRDqB0IB0reJBQKACL3YPhjwy%2B6s9l4IxGVDOPDsAUynX0DnS%2B46xPJ1OYCB2Agcq02vDFoOC3Ny0WO51oQlA97GyQJpMp9jOjsF9gQKSSFszDnDnRtjriMw6WiDnPC0WR2si3tdourwsTNC0TbmoMeUMTLDsGnR5cc/Nr4uXzfm82oAgINz7w/HzCn6QTAD0ACprRyIAfJ9iAAOjwatPy/L8JiuKlmH6I9lHfU43UIBAYOuVgLypCktAyL4JhEdB5SfCUEypPAqDwTBiIANzcfw6AmN0SAAayxBc6wlAgnRQHpS3eVtBw3bsQBE9cb37Qcx1HQSR0HQMpxnOcz04sMoJ/L9z3E40TVQZF0SIYhplDa9O03bdd1NF9EJPZVVNlUUdPvAzmCMkyzL7ZVTT3M5XyQj9zwAP3EgN03POUGz45s5PHYTJKLaTYtkmYhMkSQOhAkKEoDJTZ3S%2BdHJFJc/n5KMYwOHTkCuNz1yzcDwrUyji2NMwJiHMAwBMiZdggiL6x451Ll5UEbgmNxjIcriRQmmTB2q65yQHdKZLwOb0o6G1aAfcb6PyyRCumkjiFQN1uN4uxaIWdAVkyYBjDwiAJpAy4A0nKbFzK88rgIXpaGzBySsOSqsyMDFaDC4MMwG3imwE1L5PSvRFTwFhyXQUgJmALQ3FRiZ6OIRjTDylToZFV0IGYQlUC3OhNl0u7/yhzhMckTGvAmXgJjMSM%2BrUyLBpAfSvh%2Bc5aHmdYeVEd4oqwFgEVRd45dYRFkQgBbasp4hgEUiE7ghfHMhWYXDumtEEXTQ3iGNz4QIpOD%2BgHMxZB8sxTKtABabZELGVWiypogIIw37iH%2BjWlru97P156Uw36kU0eQBAHUFy7rtu7WHqzSyBNNTA%2BaKo7zsbfiZMwEC3QQNzIYRuKCunfbTaL2n6DsAx7LJusgaOgOafNK7iD8q2bYIL2IUlJu6yiuH1skAAJZh6IvcypJW5KB7A2fJwb0nz270UoJI05/BRqiaPxhjAmYtDS91fVRAmKgMVYBRmKff7mHlOkOVf8Tz1/c809S7JTnA3Bg5F1hnwxhMbatAPbY3sMQPGBMiYTAgJwcaAAPNEn8kz0U2iTAqH1yYkEptTFu9NzSMxtMzVm7NMZcx5mVAuR0orC0CKLYEgs5bMAVlsGYys/bqxqhHbWusdgGwHiPSecpzaWykcLO2ip4JFnDv7MRUc4781FInZOUU07rBundLOpYc66Xzo1QurDBYz2SuXSu1d9w6DSgdHeRDO5HW3GoWg7cZGfXDNokUvddIDyHj%2BBRnw/EiiATFWubYF5L1CklOJG81ogI2mgx8bkJjqhEL/BKP9aBgAGKWeCv02CsAtuJTq29lLuL3l9NSGktKlVDAMLorAQADDMAMUgpgBi7F6agLpziZByAlD0PocJHicF6QQLpgzAykFYuYXYIF%2BT8jMGYTguxJC7G4LsAAHJwE0HheCdIGNwXp/TBmkGGQMXpCgQC7FIPMgZ7TSBwFgDARAfFKSFjIBQdWqB/nsHcGMEQwAdm7BeVRFWDFKDOAWb0lM3xiAIi6bM0gaBEx4QAPK0Eqci0gWAwaiG7O8kleArhFHok8ylmBMGFEJIMW5JZlDEvWM4dE6K9BYExXMpBRgBVdBoPQJgbAOA8H4IIYQogUByDkEIPAzgnmQC6OwumXSPaOhMhIMZMhOD8keUhIoGgnraHqKYFmVhyixHiIIXw/gvhWsdREL4drKjuBZgUM1tASh1H0LkQQvqvgBuaDEL1Iamiup9U0T1bRvVdAUJM/oXAOldJ6X04l9zMGHJNB7E03Atxyr5DskCazdhoNwIQEgxoPAswmMjbwAL62cCtKMl20g5nIqWSs7gABOEC6VuDcEOQO/kA6zADs4IcjwJohBdKuaQYVDaQKcDMIcx4xz%2BSSAHXs3YJoLA3KGV0x5zzXm9s%2BT8iASB%2BLeEJOQSgOKW1gsEDRWt3rSBisYCwbs0q3Tom8CKxd3Trk5q6cMDBqFHwTDzQWotJbIUTHLZWnt7yllPmYFgdwAZQPLuFSaQ5IFDncCNSaWdkh%2BS7Enfu7NlL7nnpeW8xZXR%2B1DpHWOidU6Z1zoXRcjw4GGNnsvRhjNAxJBCduYx0TrHSAoMCCAbgQA)

We're using `std::optional` essentially just to provide uninitialized storage for our value. The whole `initializing` thing is very likely unnecessary: it avoids performing *any* move or copy constructions whatsoever. If you instead use `std::optional<std::decay_t<decltype(create(arg))>> var_opt` and `var_opt.emplace(create(arg))`, then if `create` returns by value, that value will materialize as a temporary, and a reference to that temporary will be passed to `emplace`. The final object will then be move constructed from that temporary. Generally, that's good enough.

Comment: I think this is the best answer so far. The only downside is the uninitialised memory within the optional - which is something I was trying to avoid

Answer (score -1):

I think that it is mostly dependent on the variable type.

For example, if it's a pointer (smart or dumb) you can set it to `nullptr` before the try block and check if it was assigned outside of the try block.

If it's another type that can't get `nullptr` you can use a default value if possible.
If this is not possible as well - well you should give a concrete example and maybe you could get a better answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's neither of those cases. `typeof(var)` is a Class with no default constructor.

Comment: @TobiAkinyemi And you can use a pointer to this class?

Comment: I could, but that changes (and complicates) the whole situation.

Comment: If your class support's move/copy you can use pointer just for initialization and after the try block just move/copy the value to a non-pointer variable.